# Is this punctuation correct? And what type of clause is this?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, clauses

I have this sentence which I wanted to investigate grammatically for correctness.

> He is very uneducated, which is why he cannot find work.

Is the comma correct here? Also, is "which is why he cannot find work." a dependent or independent clause? I thank all helpers.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @HotLicks thank you. Is the clause dependent?

Comment: Do some research.

Comment: @HotLicks Is this a relative clause which is thus a dependent clause?

Comment: Do some research.

Comment: Yes, the comma's correct. The last clause is an independent  (non-restrictive) relative clause, because of the comma. However, nobody says _cannot_; the word is _can't_, even written. And don't say _very uneducated_ -- just _uneducated_ is enough.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you very much, this certainly clarifies things. So a relative clause can be independent? Some references seem to indicate that relative clauses are always dependent

Comment: No, sorry, I misunderstood your question. No, a relative clause is always a dependent clause. But there are two kinds; I thought you were asking about restrictive versus non-restrictive (there are other new terms for these that some people use, and I mistook "independent" as one of them).

Comment: @JohnLawler Ah I see, thank you very much. Is this a restrictive clause then?

Comment: The relative clause in your sentence is a non-restrictive relative clause, because of the comma. That is one of the distinguishing characteristics. Another is that non-restrictive relative clauses can't use _that_, while restrictive ones can.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you kindly